# JS - What is the equivalent Mutation Observer of an EventListener that listens to messages?

Tags: javascript, iframe, communication, mutation

I am currently implementing an iframe into my web-application. This iFrame is a WYSIWYG Editor that should resize automatically based on the content inside of it. Later I also need to communicate the content from the editor to my parent application. For some time now I used EventListeners that listen to the "message" event like this:

```
window.addEventListener("message", doSomething(event);
```

And the code inside my iFrame would look like this:

```
window.top.postMesssage("a message lol", "https://example.com")
```

As of late the console tells me that EventListeners are deprecated and I should use Mutation Observers (MO) instead. What option in my MO should I use so that it listens to messages?

I found a list of options but they don't seem to fit the purpose.

```
let options = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  characterData: false,
  subtree: false,
  attributeFilter: ['one', 'two'],
  attributeOldValue: false,
  characterDataOldValue: false
};
```

Here tiptapeditor is the iFrame node and I was hopeing to get at least a response of any kind when typing inside the editor.

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('tiptapeditor')
    const observerConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
    const callback = (mutations) => {
      for (const mutation of mutations) {
        if (mutation.type == "childList") {
          console.log("Child mutation detected")
        }
        if (mutation.type == "chatacterData") {
          console.log("Character mutation was detected")
        }

        if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
          console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        }
      }
    }
    let observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig)
```

Comment: I couldn't find any evidence of message event (or "_EventListeners_" in general) being deprecated. Are you sure the warning was about message event?